# How to hide redirect from the one of the User-Agents

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, seo, user-agent, googlebot

I have an URL and I want to have this configuration for it:

- Googlebot should be redirected to page *x*,
- other User-Agent should be redirected to page *y*.

How can I hide the 301 redirect from Googlebot and redirect this url to other adress? Should I edit .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably do this using rewrite conditions and rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot
RewriteRule ^mypage /redirect [L,R=301]
```

So this would redirect requests with a user agent that contains the word `Googlebot` from `http://example.com/mypage` to `http://example.com/redirect`